# Prove that n^3 - n is a multiple of 6 for all positive integral values of n

Tags: solution-verification

> Prove that
> $$n^3 - n$$
> is a multiple of 6 for all positive integral values of n

Does positive integral values of n refer to values of n once the expression is integrated to $$1/4n^4 - 1/2n + c$$
How do you deal with the constant of integration in a proof like this?

Comment: Positive integral values of $n$ means positive integers $n$.

Comment: It has nothing to do with integration.

Comment: The property is also true for negative integers: $(-n)^3-(-n)=-(n^3-n)$ !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little fermat implies that $n^3=n$ mod $3$ and $n^3-n=n(n^2-1)=n(n-1)(n+1)$ and $n(n-1)$ is even.
$n-1,n,n+1$ are 3 consecutive numbers, one of them is divisible by $3$.

Postive integral value are elements of $\mathbb{N}$ strictly positive.

Comment: There is no need to invoke Fermat, one even and one multiple of $3$ are enough.

Answer (score 1):

$$n^3-n\equiv((n\bmod3)^3-(n\bmod3))\mod6$$

and

$$0^3-0=0,1^1-1=0,2^3-2=6.$$